# Salesforce - Best way to pass namespace__ (e.g:Apttus__, svmax__ etc) to get('obj').getDescribe().fields.getMap(); method

Tags: apex, namespace

We have a requirement to prefix namespace__ value object at below code. For e.g : For template, need to prefix Apttus__, so the object value will be Apttus_template .
We have multiple managed packages installed and in some cases need to pass Apttus__, in some cases need to pass svmx__ etc . Could you please let me know what is the best way to identify the correct namespace__ value and prefix it to object .

```
Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('object').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

The namespace prefix is part of the object API name. You should be storing the complete ("fully-qualified") object API name. So if you have an object called `apttus__Template__c`, you must always use that name to reference it - never `Template__c`, which is incorrect.

Then, pass the entire fully-qualified API name to any dynamic schema access methods you use:

```
Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('apttus__Template__c').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Comment: You will need to change your design. That won’t work. Use the Description or Help Text to store the API name, or Custom Metadata

Comment: Thank you David for the response., however I am using object names as field names in another object (e.g: In Masking Input ID object, created lookup fields for Contact, User and Agreement  with field names as Contact, User and Template respectively . I actually wanted Template field name as Apttus__Template, however system didn't allow double underscore in field name ) . So thinking to use object field name as Template__c, while calling dynamic schema access methods, prefix namespace Apttus_Template__c) . Please suggest

Comment: As I said above, that won't work. You will need to change your design.